# Eclipse: Search => File => 'Enclosing project' option greyed out

Tags: eclipse

I want to search only in my current project but the "enclosing project" option is grayed out most of the time. Sometimes, it is not greyed out... Bug ? Or I am missing something ?

I am on Mac OSX.

Comment: did you make sure that you "are on" a file that can have an enclosing project? If not open one, place your cursor inside and try again. Btw this has nothing to do with Android...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to have the focus (by clicking) on a file, that is in a project. This can be done for example by clicking on a file in the Project Explorer or clicking in the Editor View of a file.

If your focus is not on a file (for example, when you click on the Console before searching), the option "enclosing project" is disabled, because no file within a project is selected you could search in.

Comment: I  know about this but I still have the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the "File name patterns" field has a value. An empty value disables the Search button.